# Populate dropdown with Outlook distribution list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement that I have to have two SharePoint fields, "Project Team" and "Team Members", both dropdown types. "Project Team" will have Outlook distribution list (eg "ProjectA Team", "ProjectB Team" are distribution lists in outlook each have several members).

The requirement is that if "ProjectA Team" is selected for "Project Team" field, "Team Members" field should be populated with members in the "ProjectA Team" only.

Two problems: 1) how to make sure only distribution lists are populated for "Project Team"
2) How to populate  "Project Team" with members in the "Project Team" list

Does anybody know how to accomplish this? What will be the best approach to take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this depends on the versions of Sharepoint and Outlook you are using, and how integrated you have them already...  I found this site, which might be useful to you.
The specific article in the link is about integrating Sharepoint 2007 and Outlook 2007.

http://www.outlookexchange.com/Articles/JasonSherry/sherry_c24p1.asp

I hope this is helpful.  It may not address your specifics in grabbing the exact group you want.  If you can't easily get the values you want from the Sharepoint/Outlook interfaces, you might have to get the information you need programmatically in .NET from Active Directory, using System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer for the link, but Outlook has been integrated fully and I can access names and distribution lists. My problem is how to make sure to get only distribution lists for "Project Team" field and not individual names. The second problem is how to populate the second field with names of individuals only based on the selection for the first field.

Comment: Anybody else about this issue please help!